# create two nft collections from one smart contract in OpenSea

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155, opensea

I want to list two collections on Opensea but instead of creating two smart contracts for that, I want to create only one (to save gas fees of uploading a contract).

the only two ways I found to create a collection on OpenSea are:

1. import an existing contract and it will automatically detect all the minted NFTs and display them.
2. create items manually with OpenSea UI and add them to a collection that is also created from the UI (without any code required)

I am assuming that this should be possible because when I created a collection and an NFT from the UI (on polygon) I saw in polygonscan that my nft smart contract (I found the address in the nft details) contains a lot of transactions and tokens - so that means that OpenSea uses one smart contract to represent many tokens and each token can be on different collection (fix me if I'm wrong)

so, assuming that, is there a way to import an existing contract and select prefixes of ids or a range of ids (of minted NFTs)
and show them as one collection in OpenSea? or is there another marketplace that supports this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to your question?